# Flutter : setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Actually I am new to flutter. Here is my code for splash screen.

```
  void main() async {
     WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    runApp(MyApp());
    }

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
 debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
 title: 'Meet Up',
 theme: ThemeData(
   primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
 ),
   home: IntroScreen(),);

}
}

class IntroScreen extends StatefulWidget{

@override
_IntroScreenState createState() => _IntroScreenState();
}

class _IntroScreenState extends State<IntroScreen> {

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();

FirebaseAuth auth =  FirebaseAuth.instance;
if (auth.currentUser != null)
  {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home(uid: auth.currentUser.uid)),
    );
  }
else
  {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUp()),
    );
   }

 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return new SplashScreen(
      seconds: 5,
      title: new Text('Welcome To Meet up!',
      style: new TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 20.0
      ),),
    image: Image.asset('assets/images/dart.png',fit:BoxFit.scaleDown),
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    styleTextUnderTheLoader: new TextStyle(),
    photoSize: 100.0,
    onClick: ()=>print("flutter"),
    loaderColor: Colors.red
);
}
}
```

I am getting below error:

> The following assertion was thrown building Builder:
> setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
> This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the
> process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase
> only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework
> builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built.
> Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
> The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
> Overlay-[LabeledGlobalKey#5e01c]

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: @SingleSoul any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

try to add a timer inside  initState like

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    Timer(new Duration(seconds: 2), () {
     .
     .
     .
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```